# Trigger countdown timer in email from the time it is sent, automatically

Tags: timer, email

I am looking for a way where I can integrate a countdown timer in the email. This timer should last for one week from the time email is sent. The trick here is that the timer should start automatically once the email is sent and should expire exactly in a week after receiving in the inbox, so this can be integrated in automated email campaigns. Pre-defined timers with specified start/end date is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar task. After the user has registered on our website, we created him a coupon for the product, which was valid for 1 day and we sent a letter to him with this coupon. We wanted to add a countdown timer to this letter.
we tried many services, but we couldn`t find what we needed until we came across this site https://promofeatures.com/create-countdown-timer-for-email

They made the "Dynamic start date" control in the "Transaction" tab and that was what we needed. The essence of this button is that in the counter URL you need to specify the parameter "start_date" (counter start date), we need to specify this date, for example, manually write in the email letter (if the distribution service does not allow specifying such a date format)
or using a code (just such a letter we sent through our server), asking our developers to collect this date programmatically in a email letter, which was not a big deal.
The date format itself is clear:
d-m-y, where d - the day of sending, m - month, y – year
Th: m: s, where T - indicates that it is time, h - hours, m - minutes, s – seconds
Z + h: m, where Z - indicates the time zone, time can be either "+" or "-", h - hours of the zone, m - minutes of the zone, this value is +00: 00 UTC by default

Our developers used PHP code in the letter:

```
<img src="https://m.promofeatures.com/yv?start_date=
<?= date('d-m-Y\Th:m:s')?>Z-08:00" alt="https://promofeatures.com
" />
```

and in some emails we wrote it manually and at the moment the code would look like this:

```html
<img src="https://m.promofeatures.com/yv?start_date=05-11-2019T09:11:54Z-08:00
" alt="https://promofeatures.com
" />
```

I hope this helps you if your question is still actual